# Менять цвет Rectangle програмно WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Есть массив фигур, есть цикл в котором должен меняться цвет определенной фигуры на форме.
Но цикл меняет цвет лишь в массиве. Как реализовать связь между массивом и Childrens грида?

```
//массив фигур
private Rectangle[,] rField;

//Участок кода заполнения массива
rField = new Rectangle[HeigthSize, WidthSize];
for (int i = 0; i < HeigthSize; i++)
{
for (int j = 0; j < WidthSize; j++)
    {
          rField[i, j] = new Rectangle();
          Grid.SetColumn(rField[i, j], j);
          Grid.SetRow(rField[i, j], i);
          rField[i, j].MouseDown += this.rctnField_MouseDown;
          rField[i, j].Stroke = Brushes.Cyan;
          rField[i, j].StrokeThickness = 0.5;
          rField[i, j].Fill = Brushes.White;
          GameGridField.Children.Add(rField[i, j]);
     }
}
//Участок кода в котором должен меняться цвет фигуры
while(true)
{
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
     if (rField[1, 1].Fill == Brushes.Black)
         rField[1, 1].Fill = Brushes.White;
     else
         rField[1, 1].Fill = Brushes.Black;
}
```

п.с. Делаю игру Жизнь, храню не все поле а только живые клетки, вот ищу способы реализовать поле. Может есть какие то более действенные методы, буду рад прочитать.

Comment: Во-первых, никакого `Thread.Sleep`, вы же вешаете интерфейс. Во-вторых, почему не MVVM?

Comment: Не MVVM потому что его еще не знаю, и представления не имею как реализовать. Это фактически мое первое самостоятельное приложение на WPF. С Thread.Sleep понял, уберем.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что всё меняется как надо. Просто из-за `Sleep` вы **не видите** изменений, т. к. UI-поток блокирован бесконечным циклом. Попробуйте такой код:

```
async Task ChangeColorPeriodically()
{
    while(true)
    {
         await Task.Delay(1000); // <--
         if (rField[1, 1].Fill == Brushes.Black)
             rField[1, 1].Fill = Brushes.White;
         else
             rField[1, 1].Fill = Brushes.Black;
    }
}
```